# Insert values from one column to another column in a different table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Please can someone assist ,

I have two tables, Item table and Import table with many rows

I need to insert Import.Price into Item.BuydownPrice

where the import.barcode = item.itemlookupcode

Kind Regards

Comment: What have you tried? Show the effort you have attempted to do and we will assist you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are confusing concepts. Inserting values from one table's column into another table's column is very straightforward. However, in that context, that `where` condition wouldn't make much sense.

It sounds to me (but tell me if I'm wrong) that you are trying to add the `Price` column to your `Item` table with a *join*:

```
select a.*, b.Price as BuyDownPrice
from item a
left join import b
  on a.itemlookupcode = b.barcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update a

 set a.BuydownPrice = b.Price
FROM         BuydownPrice AS a INNER JOIN
                      Item AS b ON a.barcode = b.itemlookupcode
```

Comment: Please give more explanations on how this solves the issue